# Adding an object to array but still the content length is zero

Tags: c++, objective-c, arrays, box2d

I have an ivar, `NSMutableArray *bodies;`. I allocate and initialize it inside the init method. Then in another place I'm doing the following:

```
b2Body *body=_world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
NSValue *bodyValue=[NSValue valueWithPointer:body];
[bodies addObject:bodyValue];
```

When I debug the code the body is a valid object but although I add it to the bodies array, the array remains empty. If I do something like this

```
[bodies addObject:@"An object"];
```

then the count of the objects in bodies is 1. What might be the problem? I needed a way to store C++ objects into a mutable array.

Comment: Yeah, but all the threads are answered making a conclusion that the NSMutableArray was probably not initialized. It's not the case with me. I have initialized it in the init method. And besides that, why does a string object get added to the same array?

Comment: Check the value of `bodies` right before you add `bodyValue`.

Comment: It's a valid body. Because I use it afterwards

Comment: The value of `bodies`, the _array_, not `bodyValue`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, yes, I really was messing everything up with reallocating the filled array afterwards. So, I voted to get the thread closed.